# There is no simple group of order $pq^2$.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I want to prove following:

> Suppose $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Then there is no simple group of order $pq^2$.

If $|G|=pq^2$, then there are two Sylow subgroups of order $p$ and $q$. Then I think I need to use third Sylow theorem. Third Sylow theorem implies that $n_p\mid q$. Thus $n_p=1$ or $n_p=q$. When $n_p=1$ we are done. So suppose $n_p=q$. Then how do I proceed the proof?

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3070142/11619).

Comment: It is also possible that $n_p=q^2$. For example $A_4$ has $4=2^2$ Sylow $3$-subgroups.

Comment: But think about the rest of the Sylow theorems and $n_q$ as well. The Sylow $q$-subgroups are abelian. If any two of them intersect non-trivially, the non-identity elements in there have very large centralizers.

Comment: Close to being a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210663/11619). I'm not sure I want to use my dupehammer vote right away without a chance for someone to air objections.